# How to use setLabelCount(...) in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

[image]

I have used `barChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(5);` and it returns labels as `0.00, 20.00, 40.00, 60.00` but I want `0.00, 25.00, 50.00, 75.00, 100.00`.

I want to show 100 also. is there any possibilities?

**Update**

I have added following lines,

```
barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(100);
barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
barChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(5);
```

Now the output is

```
0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0
```

So I changed it to following,

```
barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(100);
barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
barChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(4);
```

Now the output is

```
0.0, 30.0, 60.0, 90.0
```

But I need the following output.

```
0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version has method as `public void setLabelCount(int count, boolean force)`

ex:

```
barChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(5,true);
```

This will give the exact output.

**Thanks for the fix @Philipp Jahoda**

Answer (score 1):

May be you could set the custom y axis value via `ValueFormatter`.
Such as:

```
public class CustomValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    public CustomValueFormatter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return (value/20)*25 + " "; // transfer the number to meet your want.
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what value passed to `getFormattedValue`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [YAxis documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-(YLabels)). You will notice a method called `setAxisMaxValue(...)`.

- set the max value to 100
- set the min value to 0
- set the label count to 5

And you will achieve what you want.

For more custom formatting, check out the [ValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface).

Comment: doesnt work for me either, I think the height also is based on values. Why is this so hard to accomplish?